# Create call back for closure / modular pattern of javascript

Tags: javascript, closures, modular

I have a question regarding how to make a callback in module / closure pattern in javascript. I have the code named: `module.js`

```
 (function(callback){ 
   var m = {}

   function create(){
     ...
     let session;
     ...
     callback(session);
     ...
   }
   m['create'] = create;
   return m;
 })()
```

and I have file named: `main.js` where this file is **entry point for babel/webpack**

```
(function(window){
    'use strict';

    var module = require('./module');

    if(typeof(Module) === 'undefined'){
        window.Module = module;
    }
    else{
        console.log("Module already defined.");
    }
})(window);
```

and then by using babel + webpack, i produce new javascript as transpiled to ES5, named `me.js` 
I include this `me.js` into my `index.html` and use the javascript with the following way

```
...
function onCreate(session){ console.log(session) }
window.Module.create(onCreate);
...
```

but it seems the onCreate method is not running

Comment: Hi @MichalHainc thanks for your comment, can you show me where the parameter should i put?

Comment: First off, drop the IIFE pattern when you are working with modules. They already come equipped with their own scopes!

Answer (score 0):

You may want to export sth in your module? Like

```
module.exports=(function(){ 
  var m = {}
  function create(callback){//goes here
      ...
      let session;
      ...
      callback(session);
      ...
  }
  m['create'] = create;
  return m;
 })();
```